# How to add shared cooldown to multiple discord.py commands

Tags: discord.py, python-decorators

I'm currently using the

`@commands.cooldown(1, 60, bucket)`

Decorator for Discord.py commands and this works partially. Say I have two seperate functions: `func_a()` and `func_b()`. I need to have it so when a user calls either `func_a()` **or** `func_b()` the cooldown is applied to both.

Example: User calls `func_a()`, user waits 10 seconds, but the cooldown is 60 seconds long. User calls `func_b()`, bot replies *"Please wait 50 seconds to use this command"*

**Edit:**
Using the solution below, for those that want the Blacklist (or Whitelist) functionality, alter the code to be the following:

```
    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(ctx.message)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if ctx.author.id not in self.blacklist:
            return True
        else:
            if retry_after:
                # You're rate limited, send message here
                await ctx.send(f"Please wait {round(retry_after)} seconds to use this command.")
                return False
            return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be by putting all the commands in a Cog, and using `commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown`

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user) # Change it accordingly

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(ctx.message)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if retry_after:
            # You're rate limited, send message here
            await ctx.send(f"Please wait {round(retry_after, 2)} seconds to use this command.")
            return False

         return True

    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Foo")

    @commands.command()
    async def bar(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Bar")

    @foo.error
    @bar.error
    async def cog_error_handler(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            pass # Empty error handler so we don't get the error from the `cog_check` func in the terminal


bot.add_cog(SomeCog(bot))
```

Sadly there's no docs about it so I can't give you the link, if you have any questions you can add them in the comments ↓

Comment: Luckily I've got them in a cog so that should be easy. Do you know if reset cooldown works too? I've got a whitelist check that uses after_invoke to reset the cooldown if the ctx.user is on the whitelist

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, you should experiment with that